# Monodroid: Test app performance

Tags: android, performance

I am using xamarin android for app development. How can i test the performance of android app Like heap memory and allocation, memory usage and all?
Is there any proper mechanism for that? Is it possible to test in Xamarin Studio?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: No. But you can measure some things in [DDMS](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

Comment: yup, DDMS is useful for this, but just read this link, if it should be useful for you:http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/memory_perf_best_practices/